Can a laundry sink drain into a washing machine stand pipe?
I have a properly vented 2" ABS stand pipe for my washing machine to drain into.
I want to add a laundry sink nearby. Can I drain the sink into the stand pipe using a wye? (e.g. with no P-trap under the sink - the sink drain line would run horizontally with a proper slope directly to the wye).

How is the existing stand pipe vented?

There's a 1.5" vent that goes up through the wall. I think somewhere near the attic (above all other drains anyway) the vent attaches to the main 3" wet vent that penetrates the roof.

Like this? https://www.reddit.com/r/Plumbing/comments/15tgs9n/is_this_dwv_design_for_a_utility_sink_next_to/

Exactly like that :) I saw that link when searching before asking, but I also saw conflicting opinions about it.

It may have to do with local plumbing codes.  Do you know if your area follows UPC or IPC or something entirely different?

you may find that suds accumulate in the sink

From a practical point of view: There is some chance of water backing up into the sink during  the washing machine's drain cycle. Harmless as far as the plumbing is concerned, but could be a nuisance if the sink isn't large enough to contain that. A slop sink should be large enough that this isn't a problem. A bathroom vanity sized sink may not be. And if course you may want to make sure the sink is empty before running the laundry.
I have no idea what current code would have to say about it.

It used to be common for washing machines to drain into slop sinks.
